# How to import .zip data to neo4j?

Tags: amazon-s3, neo4j

I have a CSV file which is zipped and stored on s3, I'm planning to import the file directly from the URL. I'm not able to find any way of doing that in Neo4j official docs.

Answer (score 1):

LOAD CSV can do this. neo4j-import has the same underlying file reader and so can read zipped files directly, although it seems to be lacking URL support currently.